# How to exclude language dlls from publish in dotnet core

Tags: .net-core

When I use `dotnet publish`, dotnet generates a bunch of folders `de`, `es`, `fr` and so on, that seems to just contain language specific information. Is there some way to not make it generate those?

We only run out web-app on servers with English locale, so they will never get used. And they are somewhat a waste of space in our docker containers.

Answer (score 4):

Add `<SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>` to a `PropertyGroup` in your `.csproj` file